# how to display text in a div like a triangle shape dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to have a block of dynamic text in a div fill a downward triangle shape. Is there any way to achieve this with either `CSS` or `Javascript`?

**The text in a div is coming from database.so want to do it as dynamic.**

```
         Marketing teams input produce cross purposing in view of goal
            alignments due to knowledge paucity, necessitating work
               flow education and orientation. Media sourcing as
                  an acquisition strategy is counterproductive
                     in a internet environment in virtual 
                        component methodology. Imaging
                                   through
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: [Fixed (slight logic error)](http://jsfiddle.net/un5epcu6/)

Comment: Thanks charles for your help! But i don't want to split the text based on space delimiter if the word is long then the alignment is not coming correctly!!

Comment: Shouldn't be that hard to change my code to split it every N characters, and then if N+1 its a space leave it alone, otherwise, subtract 1 and insert a hyphen.

Comment: [I wasn't quite happy with it =/ Fixed edge cases, and made it easier to read.](http://jsfiddle.net/87zhyht3/1/) It won't work if your first row width is to small still, but I think that's more of external issue.